# Is there a way to load data from BigQuery to Google Sheets with Google Apps Script on append-only mode?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I've been dealing with data extraction from BQ to GSheets due to a business/operational need, but I'd like to automate it as much as I can.

I've created a query that extracts the last 24h events of a given entity, and I'd like that the people involved would only be able to see these last 24h events. Thing is that, given the GoogleApps script I'm using (which you'll find below), I can't find a way to append the results: the results are over-written every time the GoogleApps script runs.

I found [writeDisposition](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.WriteDisposition.html), but it seems like it only applies for tables :/

BTW, I want to append the results because I need weekend data to be saved and stacked. The idea is that when people grab the data in the gsheets, they delete it and wait for the new data the next day.

Thanks a lot!

GoogleApps script:

```
function runQuery() {
  var projectId = '123456789';
  

  var request = {
    query: 'SELECT * FROM `mytable.example`',
    useLegacySql: "false"
  };
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;


  // Get all the rows of results.
  var rows = queryResults.rows;
  while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      pageToken: queryResults.pageToken
    });
    rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
  }

  if (rows) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('query_results');

    // Append the headers.
    var headers = queryResults.schema.fields.map(function(field) {
      return field.name;
    });
    //sheet.appendRow(headers);

    // Append the results.
    var data = new Array(rows.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var cols = rows[i].f;
      data[i] = new Array(cols.length);
      for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
        data[i][j] = cols[j].v;
      }
    }
    
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, headers.length).setValues(data);
    Logger.log(data.length);
    Logger.log('Results spreadsheet created: %s',
        spreadsheet.getUrl());
  } else {
    Logger.log('No rows returned.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append your current data to the last row of the sheet, use this sample code:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('query_results');
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

What it does?

1. Get the sheet's last row index using [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
2. Select the range to write the new data, increment the last row by 1 which will act as the start row for the new data to be added.

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues so i could update accordingly. I was not able to replicate your issue due to lack of sample data.

Comment: Yep, that definitely worked! In my previous query, I was setting the getRange() at 2 (2nd row), while with getLastRow()+1 does the trick! Thanks :D