# "Out of memory error" in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I am trying to fetching data from BQ and put it to google sheet using app script but getting this error :

[image]

My assumption it's because my bq result is very large which is **1 mill++ values = 90k rows x 20 columns**, is there any way to solve this ? like optimize the script or something else.
I am using this script :

```
function test_function() {
 // Replace this value with the project ID listed in the Google
 // Cloud Platform project.
 DriveApp.getRootFolder(); //enable google drive credential
 const projectId = 'project-id';


 const request = {
   // TODO (developer) - Replace query with yours
   query: 'SELECT * FROM DUMMY',
   location: "project-region",
   useLegacySql: false
 };
 let queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
 let jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;
 var jobLocation = queryResults.jobReference.location;


 // Check on status of the Query Job.
 let sleepTimeMs = 10000;
 while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
   Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
   sleepTimeMs *= 2;
   queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId,{location: jobLocation});
 }


 // Get all the rows of results.
 let rows = queryResults.rows;
 while (queryResults.pageToken) {
   queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
     pageToken: queryResults.pageToken,
     location: request.location
     //location : bigQuerySettings.location
   });
   rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
 }


 if (!rows) {
   Logger.log('No rows returned.');
   return;
 }
 var sheetid = 'spreadsheet id'
 var opensheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetid).getSheetByName("sheet name") //open sheet by id and name
 var sheet = opensheet.clearContents() ;


 // Append the headers.
 const headers = queryResults.schema.fields.map(function(field) {
   return field.name;
 });
 sheet.appendRow(headers);


 // Append the results.
 var data = new Array(rows.length);
 for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   const cols = rows[i].f;
   data[i] = new Array(cols.length);
   for (let j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
     data[i][j] = cols[j].v;
   }
 }
 sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, headers.length).setValues(data);


 Logger.log('Query Completed of : %s',
     sheet.getName());
```

Thank you!

I am expecting to get solution for this

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the error line of your showing script from your question. Where does the error occur in your showing script?

Comment: You can try sending the data to sheet for each set of rows instead of concatting everything here:`rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);`

Comment: Hi @Tanaike no worries, So the error occurs after I run the script; however, the error is not showing for which line of the script. Thanks !

Comment: Hi @TheMaster Apparently I am not really an expert with app scripts bcs that script I got from the internet. Can you shed some light on which part of my script I need to change? That would really be helpful, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this [sample code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery#sample_code) that you've followed isn't designed to handle large sets of data. The problem lies on the `while` loop to fetch all the pages of BigQuery data, then dump it all at once on Google Sheet, this method is inefficient and eats up memory allocation as it temporarily holds **all** the data before writing them on your file.

You can explore batching your data prior to writing to sheets or directly writing them as they are read by using `sheet.appendRow(row)` to ease up memory usage.

Here are other resources you can use as reference:

- [AppScript: Use Connected Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/connected-sheets)
- [BigQuery: Using Connected Sheets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/connected-sheets)
- [Increased row limits in Connected Sheets for BigQuery](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/09/increased-row-limits-in-connected-sheets.html)
- [Usage and Limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits#increase)
- [Is there a way to load data from BigQuery to Google Sheets with Google Apps Script on append-only mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68456291/is-there-a-way-to-load-data-from-bigquery-to-google-sheets-with-google-apps-scri)

Comment: thanks, yes I suspect one of the reason because of the looping stuff, however since I am not really expert in google script hence not really know how to change the code, but I will try to do it and come back!